Gnuplot locks the script after loading it
The Gnuplot-Workflow "Gnuplot-Console + Editor (Geany) using Gnuplot 5.4.x and Linux (Xubuntu 22.04) does'nt work by using Windows 10.
Loading and running the Gnuplot-script via "load myscript.gnuplot" is possible.
However, when I try to make any changes in the "myscript.gnuplot", I'm uable to save the file.
Gnuplot seems to put a lock on this file.
I got the following error message from my german Gnuplot:
"Fehler beim Speichern der Datei. Fehler beim Umbenennen der temporären Datei: Permission denied.
Die Datei ist möglicherweise nicht vollständig auf der Festplatte gespeichert."
Translation:
"Error saving the file. Error renaming the temporary file: Permission denied.
The file may not be completely saved on the hard disk."
Using an older portable version of Gnuplot (5.0.x) and the same Windows installation there is no lock and all things are working as expected - like within my Linux ;-).
After closing Gnuplot-Console, the script can be saved again (for both Gnuplot-versions).
Why does Gnuplot behave so differently for different versions?
Am I missing something?
Is it possible to use the workflow (Gnuplot + editor) without closing the Gnuplot-Console with a Gnuplot version 5.4.x using Windows 10?

Are you sure Geany doesn't play a role here? I cannot reproduce this with gnuplot 5.4.6, Window10 and Notepad++ as editor.

It seems pretty clear that you have discovered a code regression
in Gnuplot 5.4 relative to 5.0.
Recommend you file a bug report with the maintainer.
This SO question is already a pretty good bug report,
it's just missing some details like e.g.
version 5.4.10
or whatever you're actually running.
Also, it would improve the bug report if you could narrow down
that e.g. 5.2.3 does not exhibit the symptom, yet 5.4.1 does.
It's worth noting the current release is
Gnuplot 6.0.1.
You should definitely test whether it exhibits the same symptom.
background
unix
Consider processes A and B, on a unix-like (linux) OS.
Process A opens version 1 of some giant numbers.csv file and reads
the first few lines, then pauses.
Process B either deletes that file, or equivalently
writes version 2 on top of that filename, perhaps with fewer lines.
In either case process A still has an open file
descriptor to version 1, and can un-pause and continue
to successfully read all lines until EOF.
Only when A does a close() will version 1 storage
be reclaimed by the filesystem.
Meanwhile B, or any new process, can open("numbers.csv")
and view the version 2 figures.
windows
Now consider a pair of processes A, B running on just about
any MS OS, such as Windows 10, using local native filesystem.
There's no way to support concurrent access to both
versions 1 and 2 of the spreadsheet.
So the OS enforces a lock.
As long as A has a file descriptor open on numbers.csv,
for reading or for writing, B is locked out.
If B attempts to open() it will receive an error.
If B attempts to rename readme.txt on top of numbers.csv
it will receive an error.
We don't even need two processes to reproduce this behavior.
Two different file descriptors managed by same process would suffice.
bug
This is the situation you are observing with Gnuplot.
Apparently old versions did not leak file descriptors
and they carefully closed them once they had consumed a file.
In contrast, you are reporting that 5.4 regrettably
leaves a file descriptor open for too long,
which interferes with subsequent operations.
action item
Please edit your question, post an answer, or at least a comment,
which mentions the bug report you file against 5.4. Thank you.
Hmmm, having
searched
the bug database it turns out this is a
known issue
that can be reproduced in 5.4.6.
It would be helpful if you appended your observations to that ticket.
Try to find the latest version (5.2.8?) that is known good,
and the first version which exhibits the symptom.
That would be a big help to a maintainer.
Alternatively, since the source code is available,
you might try your hand at submitting a PR with improved source code.
